# Does Linux pymssql use ODBC?

Tags: python, pymssql

I want to use `pymssql` on a 24/7 Linux production app and am worried about stability. As soon as I hear ODBC I start to have reservations, especially on Linux.

Does `pymssql` use ODBC or is it straight to freeTDS?

Comment: http://www.pymssql.org/en/latest/

Answer (score 0):

No, pymssql does not use ODBC.